# Check with Carbon if a date is on a different day

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to determine if 2 dates are on different days using Carbon. To do so, I'm using the method `diffInDays()`, but it doesn't work as I need.

An example

```
$dt1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-12 23:00:00');
$dt2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-13 8:00:00');
echo $dt1->diffInDays($dt2);
```

It says 0 because 24 hours are not past.

I thought to compare `$dt1->day` and `$dt2->day`, but if one was 2017-12-13 and the other 2018-1-13 the days would be the same, so I should check the months, the years... and I'm wondering if there is something which already does that out of the box.

Reading the documentation I can't find a method which directly does what I need: it should say "yes, $dt2 is a different day than $dt1". Is that possible with Carbon not writing a custom function?

Comment: You can do this with something like this: `$dt1->format('Ymd') < $dt2->format('Ymd');`, but you would probably have to write a custom function for that.

Comment: That is what I expected, I'll have to manage that by myself, but your hint has been of help anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ok! I'm glad to help! Just be aware that this will only check if a date is before another. So, to check if they are different, try using `!==`.

Comment: Simply: `$dt1->isSameDay($dt2)`